# styled components in functional component does not apply style to component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Typography } from 'antd';
const { Title } = Typography;
const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
    align-self: center;
    color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
`;
export function Header(props : {children : React.ReactNode}) {
    return <StyledTitle>{props.children}</StyledTitle>;
}
export default Header;
```

I want to change text color to `rgb(140, 140, 140)`. However color does not changed.

[image: Header]

I use `Header` component in other component like below.

```
import { Header } from './Header';
export function Login() {
    return(
        <Container>
            <Header>Login</Header>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

if I set `background-color: yellow;`, it applied well.

[image: Header]

Because of this, I am confused. Some styles are working and other styles are not working...

Comment: Well, if you inspect styles you will see where it is coming from. Likely antd styles are more specific than yours.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I am hard to understand how `antd` styles could be more specific than component. Could you kindly explain it for me? And how can I set my styles to be more specific than `antd`?

Comment: "how antd styles could be more specific than component", Well, tons of ways. For example those selectors might have tag names `h1.ant-typography` is more specific than just '.my-class' coming from SC. Just open dev tools and check which style effectively applies.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
color: rgb(140, 140, 140)!important;
```

Comment: No, this is the worst approach you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you explain why i should not do that in this case?

Comment: Important is an escape hatch that basically nails down property. It has priority higher than inline styles. Basically you code becomes less maintainable. Not a big deal in OPs case but might ruin overall Developer Experience if used as a general approach.